# Linux command for creating/leaving/returning to shells

Tags: linux, ssh, process

I was using a command a long time ago to manage my background processes and I can't remember wich one. I had to install it.

- I could create a shell and go into it
- Run a process
- Leave the shell with something like <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>
- return whenever I want

And it works with multiple shells

Any idea what program I was using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Out of the two I prefer tmux. It has easier configuration, more features (splits etc) and is actively under development (Screen is not). But if it's a really simple task, screen does the job just fine.

Read more about tmux in [tmux vs GNU Screen.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen)